# Consideration for these tags

Tags: discussion, tags

As grammar and usage of some words depends on the origin like US or UK English, So I was thinking that there must be tags about those also..

As I am not the moderator nor the one who decides tags but I fell need for those tags. Don't you feel these type of tags must be there to categorize questions?

Comment: you do get to choose some tags when you write your question, though others will help to edit them if better tags exist. So, if you think your question is about "american-english" in particular, go ahead and use that tag :)

Answer (score 6):

You mean like [american-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-english), [british-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/british-english), [indian-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-english), [australian-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-english), [canadian-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canadian-english), [non-native-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-native-english), [irish-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irish-english), [new-zealand-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-zealand-english), [hawaiian-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hawaiian-english), [kenyan-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kenyan-english), and [ugandan-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ugandan-english)? (Go ahead, click them: those are all tags that already exist. Some of them don't have any questions, but most of them do.)

Comment: Isn't there an [tag:italian-english] too?

Comment: thanks... Actually I was writing U.S. something in my question thnx for help